# Failed to display base64 image in mpdf

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I still kinda new in mpdf and i try to display an image using embedded base64 using mpdf. Below is my code.

```
$kad_photo = base64_encode($row['kad_photo']);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;');
$photo = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64, ".$kad_photo."\"/>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($photo);
```

I get this error when i put `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;`:

```
mPDF error: IMAGE Error (0f5155bea7f7e18dc9f7c35b695d1705): Error parsing JPG header
```

I got try this method and it work!

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML("<img src=".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/vms/images/logo/logo.png " . 
                 "width=\"500\" height=\"50\">");
```

**BUT FOR BASE64 I FAILED TO DISPLAY IT.**

Other than that, for `$photo`, I got `file_put_content` the string and paste it at jsfiddle and it work! But in mpdf i fail to display the base64 image.

Any suggestion why i cant show the image using embedded base64?

## Information that might needed

1. Gd module in php.ini had been enabled
2. Window 10 Single Language

Comment: Are you sure the $row['kad_photo'] contains all binary image data? Also, setting the image/jpeg header does not make sense here.

Comment: yupz, i 100% sure it contain all binary image data. Because i got file_put_content the image. And for the image/jpeg header, I thought that i need to set the image header here. I removed that already but then i still unable to display the image. Any idea what going one???

Comment: And is the image in the variable really image/jpeg?

Comment: $row['kad_photo'] actually is from the database as blob type.

Comment: Sure, but it its content-type really image/jpeg? Is it not some other image type?

Comment: I sorry, but how to check if the content is image/jpeg? When i insert it into database i just decode the image and save it into database. I using heidimysql. 

Because i got test the $photo in browser and i can display it.

Answer (score 7):

I solved my problem. This how i solved it.

change this

```
$photo = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64, ".$kad_photo."\"/>";
```

to this

```
$photo = "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64, ".$kad_photo."\"/>";
```

Comment: You dont know single quotes?

Comment: I had a similar problem and it seems that the JPG was the problem in the "...data:img/JPG..." (changing this to ...data:img/PNG... resolved it)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the image type was set incorrectly in some user data I was working with (set to png but the image data was jpeg).

`$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;` showed "Error parsing PNG identifier"

Browsers seem to be able to figure it out and display the image anyway, but MPDF is picky.

I figured this out by pasting my base64 data into an [online decoder](http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image) and trying various encodings.

Also, it seems like JPEG data begins with /j9/ if that helps anyone.

Comment: Perfect, this solves my problem.

if(substr($item,0,4) == '/9j/')

Answer (score 1):

```
$html= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( 
stripslashes($row['kad_photo']) ).'"/>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('My.pdf','D');
```

**please try this one.**

Comment: explanation needded

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I've fixed it just added correct mime type that I've got from header from response where I've got content of image for base64

```
            /** @var \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $value */
            $value = $result['value'];

            $contents = $value->getBody()->getContents();
            $this->data['images'][] = 'data:' . $value->getHeader('Content-Type')[0] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($contents);
```